# How make ContainerRequestFilter filter on multiple annotations, but 1 at a time in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I made a `ContainerRequestFilter` but when I add two annotations, for it to be called on any method, the method needs *both* annotations. What I want is this:

Provider:

```
@TypeA
@TypeB
@Provider
@Priority( Priorities.AUTHENTICATION )
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{ ... }
```

Some class that gets filtered:

```
@Path( "/test" )
public class TestStuff
{
    @POST
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Path( "auth" )
    @TypeA
    public Response login() { ... }

    @POST
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Path( "auth" )
    @TypeB
    public Response somethingElse() { ... }

}
```

But this does not work. It only works if I did:

```
@Path( "/test" )
public class TestStuff
{
    @POST
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Path( "auth" )
    @TypeA
    @TypeB
    public Response login() { ... }

    @POST
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Path( "auth" )
    @TypeA
    @TypeB
    public Response somethingElse() { ... }

}
```

How do I make a filter match on an "OR" of the types?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [Name Binding](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9667), you could use a [Dynamic Binding](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9740). You just need to implement a `DyanamiCFeature`, and check if the method has the annotation to determine if the filter should be registered for that method.

```
public class AuthDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo info, FeatureContext context) {
        Method method = info.getResourceMethod();
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(TypeA.class)
            || method.isAnnotationPresent(TypeB.class)) {

            context.register(new AuthenticationFilter());
            // or context.register(AuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just register the feature with the application. Or if you add `@Provider` on the feature, and you have package/classpath scanning enabled, it will automatically get registered.